# ASP.NET VB DataGridView's DropDownList does not fire EditItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview

I have the following code. Such that, a dropdownlist is in the datagridview with 4 set options. I have few editable columns as well. I am trying to achieve the following:

1. When I select "CCCC" in the dropdownlist, I should be able edit just one column say the header called "CD"
2. When I select "BBBB" in the dropdownlist, I should be able to edit all the columns except the one under column header "CD"
3. I have VB code to make the "Save" image button visible when row is in the edit mode. When I click the save image button, the website should come out of the edit mode
4. When one of the rows is in the edit mode, then other rows should not go in edit mode.

I am new here and hence require lot of support.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action Requested" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="black" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Large"/>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:dropdownlist ID="ddl_Validation" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GV_Sec_Validation_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Select a value" Value="aaaa"/>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="BBBB" Value="bbbb"/>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="CCCC" Value="cccc"/>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="DDDD" Value="dddd"/>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="EEEE" Value="eeee"/>
                            </asp:dropdownlist>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="IbtnSave" ImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" runat="server" CommandName="Save" ToolTip="Save" Width="10px" Height="10px" Visible="false" />                                               
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="IbtnEdit" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" Width="10px" Height="10px" Visible="false" />                            
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="IbtnCancel" ImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" Width="10px" Height="10px" Visible="false" /> 
                        </ItemTemplate>                     
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SR" ControlStyle-Width="30px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDomain_SR" Text='<%# Eval("SR") %>' runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDomain_SR" Text='<%# Eval("SR") %>' runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CD" ControlStyle-Width="30px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDomain_CD" Text='<%# Eval("CD") %>' runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDomain_CD" Text='<%# Eval("CD") %>' runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DI" ControlStyle-Width="30px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDomain_DI" Text='<%# Eval("DI") %>' runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDomain_DI" Text='<%# Eval("DI") %>' runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: too broad post.

Comment: Hi Asif, thank you for the read. You can also take up partial cases. I would be helped immensely if you can pick #1. Thanks.